# Best way to return error in UDF VBA function

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I have an Excel VBA function with error handling that returns a `Double`.
What is the best way to return the error if the function fails?

At the moment if it fails it returns a 0, but 0 could be a valid return from the function.

Is it simply to change the function to return a `Variant` and then return the error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can return any of the `#` type errors with `CVErr()`; E.g. to return `#VALUE!`

```
Public Function Foo(i As Long) As Variant '//must return a variant
If i < 0 Then
    Foo = CVErr(xlErrValue)
Else
    Foo = 3 / i
End If
End Function
```

Comment: For complete list of xlErr types visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/cell-error-values